# Relation between representativeness of a sample and sample size

Tags: sampling, small-sample, representative

Is there a relation between sample size and a representative sample? Does the sample size affect the representativeness of a sample?

---

**Context:**  I used cluster sampling to get a sample of the study population. I calculated the needed size of the sample to do so beforehand. But after completing the survey, the size of the sample was less than the calculated (intended) size. Does this affect the representativeness of the sample?